# Makin a reset function for an edit form

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have form where the user can modify data and then hit send to store it at the server. I also have this reset button, where I want to be able to reset all the changes the user has made.

This is my controller:

```
controller: function($scope, $timeout, project){
  var initProject = project;
  $scope.project = project;

  $scope.reset = function(){
    console.log(initProject) //Same value as $scope.project after modifying $scope. Why?
    $scope.project = initProject;
  };
```

My idea is to store the initial resolve value (project) in a variable. Then reset the $scope to this value. But it's not working. When the user modifies the $scope.project, somehow the initProject is modified also.

Any ideas? Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to make a copy of `project`; otherwise, `project` and `initProject` will actually be the *same* object, accessed through different variables.

You can use [`angular.copy`](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.copy) for this:

> **angular.copy**
>    - function in module ng
>    Creates a deep copy of source, which should be an object or an array.

---

Just change

```
var initProject = project;
...
$scope.project = initProject;
```

to

```
var initProject = angular.copy(project);
...
$scope.project = angular.copy(initProject);
```

---

Here's [a JSFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/3PRu9/).